# Ionic 2 Android Build Prod Warning while verifying jar signing

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am getting an error while building my Ionic application, it occurs on a new app (which I started from the scratch couple of days ago). None of my old apps have this issue. The issue does not occur in any of older apps i.e., apps that are 4-5 months old.

> WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry
>      will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.

and it continues for 4-5 more files.

My environment info:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.9.1
npm   : 5.6.0 
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Is this of any security concern or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**[TEMP FIX]**: As all the file contains are version nos, for now I have removed those META files from my final apk before verification e.g., used

> sudo zip -d apkfilename.apk META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime

did the same for the rest of the six files!

Comment: How do I remove META files from the apk?