# Ionic 3 Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ionic3

I am trying to publish an android app using ionic 3, but there is an error when running

```
apksigner verify myapp.apk
```

These error shows:

```
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry
will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry
will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
WARNING: META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will not be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

**Things I already do**

- I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988727/ionic-2-android-build-prod-warning-while-verifying-jar-signing) , but I didn't know how to remove those META files. If somebody can show the directory.. help!
- Update my Angular, JDK and Android Studio
- Update version number in Config.xml

**UPDATE**

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did to resolve this issue was by reinstalling android

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

*Note, one of the plugins didn't work on latest version of android. So, I have to downgrade android version to 6.3.0

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Hope this will help others too!

Comment: We have other requirements such as I don't can revert to an older android platform version. Is it possible this is an issue with this new 7.1.0 platform version?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I already use android@6.3.0 but it don't resolve mine.

To resolve it, I follow the message and move the entry outside of META-INF. The App seems not have problems with this operation.

Comment: In my case, one of the plugins are deprecated. Hope your answer will help others too!